# How to run standalone files in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm doing small time project development using PyCharm. I use Pycharm for its intellisense features. As I develop each piece of code, I like to run it occasionally to test it. All I need at the point of development is to be able to run the file. However, when I right click and try to run a standalone file, PyCharm tries to be intelligent and shows me options to run my code with unit-tests and other fancy testing gimmicks. I don't want to deploy any testing framework at this point.

All I want is to be able to run any file as it is. But somehow, PyCharm is not allowing me to do that for every file.

I will appreciate if someone can provide a workaround for this. I'm using Python 273

Comment: Can you provide a sample file where **Run** (Ctrl+Shift+F10) doesn't work as expected?

Comment: If the file you're running has a `.py` or `.pyw` extension, PyCharm shouldn't be involved if you start it directly.

Comment: Can't you just use the [context menu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19694299/656912) on the file in the Project list?

Comment: Came here looking for how to debug files called "test_....py", and other files that match PyCharms "this is a test" pattern. Am yet to find an answer (apart from renaming the file/class/...). There must be a way to do this without manually creating a new debug-config for every such file...?

Answer (score 15):

I just came across the same problem. It was because it had a class called TestClass in the file. I changed the name of the class and then I was able to run the file as normal.

Comment: I don't know who "-1" this comment.  maybe they know a way to avoid this behavior, if so they should be USEFUL and tell us how.  But agree with the poster.  GET RID OF THE "TEST" CLASS if you dont want the menus to swap to creating a unit test run....

Comment: This was driving me bonkers because my CTRL+SHIFT+F10 reflex kept causing PyCharm to attempt to run a test suite that didn't exist all because I made a GUI window called TestWindow.  I hate that PyCharm can't tell when I'm not using tests and gives me no way to disable test behavior or a shortcut that always simply runs the current file - with no 'smart behaviors' or special 'run configurations.'  I finally got used to CTRL+SHIFT+F10 instead of F5 or F9 for "run" and it looks like even that shortcut isn't reliable. Pycharm should color classes with Test in them different or something. \rant

Answer (score 15):

You can simply choose the 'Run' entry in the context menu for the file in the Project view:

[image]

This will run the file exactly as if you had entered

python

from the command line, in the directory containing the file.

The first time you do this an entry is also added to the toolbar, which allows you to run the file with a single click

[image]

and provides options for customizing a range of options supplied automatically each time you run.