# Why nothing happen when I run Turtle in Pycharm?

Tags: python

Below is my code. However, nothing happened when I run this code in Pycharm Community Edition 2017.1.2. Can anyone help me to debug this issue? Thx.

```
import turtle

def draw_square():
    window=turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("red")
    victor=turtle.Turtle()
    victor.forward(100)

    window.exitonclick()
    turtle.done()

draw_square()
```

Comment: Could you add a print('Does this print?') statement at the bottom of your code and see if that pops up?

Comment: It didn't pop up also.. It is quite weird since now I cannot even run it (The "run" button didn't work in Pycharm).

Comment: This file folder location was: C:\Users\weil\Documents\Learn how to code\Practice\drawing.py.                                                                       
But I didn't know why Pycharm keep running another file in the same folder..                                                                                                    
The information show as below:  "C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Users/weil/Documents/Learn how to code/Practice/rename.py"
Current working directory is C:\Users\weil\Documents\Learn how to code\Practice

Process finished with exit code 0
"

Answer (score 0):

You haven't configured PyCharm correctly. If you navigate to your file in your terminal and call `python name_of_your_file.py` it should probably be executed.

In PyCharm, you need to Edit your run configuration. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301469/how-to-run-standalone-files-in-pycharm) shows how to run single files in PyCharm.

Comment: Your welcome, feel free to accept my answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

This might have something to do with the run configurations not being set correctly because the run and debug commands don't work for the currently displayed file. Try running the script using CTRL+SHIFT+F10 and that will create a run configuration for the currently displayed file and it will work. However, unless you edit your run configuration, every time you want to run the file you need to do it using CTRL+SHIFT+F10.

Comment: @victorlin83 In the project view right click on the file you want to run and try running it that way.